# Producer-Consumer. Consumer wait while all producers is done, poison pill

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have two producers and one consumer:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> integersQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);


        final Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    integersQueue.put(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (integersQueue.size() > 0) { //Wait while all producers work
                try {
                    System.out.println("GET: " + integersQueue.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        Thread thread1 = new Thread(producer);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(producer);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to stop the consumer if all producers are done. There are multiple producers, but only one consumer. I need some poison pill, but how can I specify it from different producers ? I found this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html but I don't understand how I can apply it?

Comment: “How can I as consumer of the queue to be processed as long as all producers finish the job?” does not appear to be a sentence, so I’m not sure what you’re asking.  Also, I only see one producer in your code.  And a word of advice:  put your loop *inside* your try/catch, so if an InterruptedException occurs, the thread will complete.  A thread which ignores interrupts is a rogue thread which cannot be terminated.

Comment: I mean:  I'm trying to find a way to stop the consumer if all producers are done. There are multiple producers, but only one consumer. It.s just example, I remove try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has to know how many producers exist.

If **consumer knows**, then each producer sends a poison pill when they are done, and the **consumer counts the poison pills**, ending when count equals number of producers.

If **producers know**, use an `AtomicInteger` to count, and the **last producer sends poison pill**.

If only **`main` knows**, i.e. it is the "controller", then it needs to wait for all producer threads to end, using `join()`, then **`main` sends the poison pill**.

Comment: OK. And the use of `CountDownLatch` in this case is not possible?

Comment: @All_Safe Possible? Sure, you can probably come up with some twisted code to use it, but it isn't the right tool for the job. --- I guess that `main` could use a `CountDownLatch` instead of `join()` on each thread, but why?

Comment: Will you give me example, how can I sends the poison pill from `main`?

Comment: @All_Safe Same as you'd do from a producer, you `put()` the poison pill into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

My typesafe variant of how to deal with poison pills:

```
public sealed interface BaseMessage {

    final class ValidMessage<T> implements BaseMessage {

        @Nonnull
        private final T value;


        public ValidMessage(@Nonnull T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Nonnull
        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            ValidMessage<?> that = (ValidMessage<?>) o;
            return value.equals(that.value);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ValidMessage{value=%s}".formatted(value);
        }
    }

    final class PoisonedMessage implements BaseMessage {

        public static final PoisonedMessage INSTANCE = new PoisonedMessage();


        private PoisonedMessage() {
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "PoisonedMessage{}";
        }
    }
}

public class Producer implements Callable<Void> {

    @Nonnull
    private final BlockingQueue<BaseMessage> messages;

    Producer(@Nonnull BlockingQueue<BaseMessage> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        messages.put(new BaseMessage.ValidMessage<>(1));
        messages.put(new BaseMessage.ValidMessage<>(2));
        messages.put(new BaseMessage.ValidMessage<>(3));
        messages.put(BaseMessage.PoisonedMessage.INSTANCE);
        return null;
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Callable<Void> {

    @Nonnull
    private final BlockingQueue<BaseMessage> messages;

    private final int maxPoisons;


    public Consumer(@Nonnull BlockingQueue<BaseMessage> messages, int maxPoisons) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.maxPoisons = maxPoisons;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        int poisonsReceived = 0;
        while (poisonsReceived < maxPoisons && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            BaseMessage message = messages.take();
            if (message instanceof BaseMessage.ValidMessage<?> vm) {
                Integer value = (Integer) vm.getValue();
                System.out.println(value);
            } else if (message instanceof BaseMessage.PoisonedMessage) {
                ++poisonsReceived;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid BaseMessage type: " + message);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```